# How can we listen more than one interrupts in a module on kernal?

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt

Can we listen more than one interrupts in a module?  if so, how can we be sure we will read every one of them as they come very close?   with a scope we can see the shortest elapse between signals could be as low as several hundreds nano second and i am running on a 400MHz arm9.